# How can I pass this username variable to an extended class, and best procedure

Tags: php, mysql

I have a username variable from Wordpress, by including wp-config.php. If I use on my index page, I can run following and all is ok.

```
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
```

also I can call `echo $_SESSION['username'];` which both output the username.

I have an extended class that I am trying to pass this variable into. And I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
class elFinderVolumeMySQL extends elFinderVolumeDriver {
```

Does anyone please know how to do this. I have tried absolutely everything, but I am new to php and not well up on constructors extended classes and whether I am doing something really wrong here, which may cause me problems.

Any advice greatly apreciated.

ie I need to add to this to get all ids where equal to username.

```
protected function _scandir($id) {
        $files = array();
        $sql   = 'SELECT f.id, f.parent_id, f.name, f.size, f.mtime, f.mime, f.width, f.height, ch.id AS dirs 
                FROM '.$this->tbf.' AS f 
                LEFT JOIN '.$this->tbf.' AS ch ON ch.parent_id=f.id 
                WHERE f.parent_id="'.$id.'"
                GROUP BY f.id';

        if ($res = $this->query($sql)) {
            while ($r = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                $id = $r['id'];

                $this->stat($id, false, $r);
                $files[] = $id;
            }
        }

        return $files;
    }
```

Comment: This question isn't clear. You don't pass values to classes, you pass them to functions and methods (which are just special functions). Please post [complete, concise sample code](http://sscce.org/), as explained in ["Writing the Perfect Question"](http://tinyurl.com/).

Comment: Sorry if not clear. I basically need to create a $username variable, that is available to all the functions within the class. The code is quite long but I can post a sample of one particular function within it.

Comment: You don't need to post the actual code. As stated, post complete, concise sample code (read the links), including as much of the code that involves passing the variable "to the class" as you have figured out. The method doesn't even need to be one from the class, as long as it illustrates your problem.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you're basically asking about a class or instance variable ("a [...] variable that is available to all the functions within the class"). Is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_SESSION is global by nature and is available across the script if following conditions are met:

1. You are using session_start()
2. You are not destroying sessions anywhere before trying to access them

Thus, if you are not able to access the value using $_SESSION['username'], then do check for the two conditions shared above. You can also check the destroying of session by creating a test variable under sessions and see if its value is available or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that it was so simple. I added session start but instead of using the $username variable I used the $_SESSION['username']; Many thanks for that. Is there anything wrong with using this method. I worry about stuff like sql injection etc.

Comment: Glad could help. Using global variables is always a bit tricky, as if you overwrite them by mistake at one place then every other piece of code which is using them is also affected. So do keep a check of this while working with them. As for SQL injections, if you follow proper practices then it gets difficult to break an sql statement whether its using a global variable or not.